# UICalendarView spaces between dates

Tags: ios, swiftui

I have followed a video on YouTube to create a view from the UICalendarView, however, there is a huge gap between the dates according to my requirement.

How can I reduce the spaces (horizontally and vertically) between the dates as highlighted in the attached photo.

```
import SwiftUI

struct CalendarView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UICalendarView {
        let calendarView = UICalendarView()
        calendarView.delegate = context.coordinator
        calendarView.calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
        calendarView.availableDateRange = DateInterval(start: .distantPast, end: .distantFuture)
        calendarView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        calendarView.fontDesign = .rounded
        return calendarView
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UICalendarView, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UICalendarViewDelegate {
        var parent: CalendarView
        init(parent: CalendarView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        @MainActor
        func calendarView(_ calendarView: UICalendarView, decorationFor dateComponents: DateComponents) -> UICalendarView.Decoration? {
            return nil
        }
    }
    
}



struct TasksMonthView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            CalendarView()
                .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: true)
            Spacer()
            .navigationTitle("Month's Tasks")
            .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Screen short for UICalendar View]

Comment: What happens if you set the frame on the view when you place it in SwiftUI?

Comment: It has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Running into the same issue. Only way to solve it AFAIK is to remove the `decorationFor` function altogether.